# Completely random keyboard behavior with duplicate keys and access to LaunchPad

Tags: keyboard, battery

I have the combination of multiple problems that I have seen individually in the net.

1. My keyboard repeats letters randomly. At first I thought it was only the O, but then I've seen many others. These days it stopped, but now it happens in 2.
2. In the launch pad's search bar, *all* the letters are systematically repeated, and only twice (which was not the case in point 1. where it could have been 3x or more).
3. If I copy some text using Cmd+C, it works fine (I can paste it), nevertheless

   a. It make an error sound

   b. It actually also copies the text to the LaunchPad's searchbar, which is thus prefilled when I trigger it with a pinch.

Any idea?

My main hypothesis is a combination of a dirty keyboard (why is it so hard to clean?) and I am imagining an swollen battery that could exert some pressure on the keyboard. (Mac tells me my battery needs to be serviced and I can hear some weird swelling noises, I believe).

Answer (score 2):

Open terminal and type
"killall Dock"
Should reset launchpad and stop it from happening